# How can I get data from dynamic generated controls in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, controls

I want to generate a couple of checkboxes on an ASP .NET MVC page. How can I retrieve their data in a controller after posting the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Request.Form` collection:

```
Request.Form["control-id"]
```

or declare a `FormsCollection` parameter in your action method and use it to retrieve the value.

Comment: +1: So far with the sketchiest of info in the question this is a reasonable answer.